# Syntax of calling a function in scala

Tags: scala

Hi I am studying the scala language and have a question. I am reading a book and one of the example says that 0 to 2 is same as (0).to(2). How can I interpret this syntax?? I mean, I can see that to is a function that takes one integer value as its parameter. But what is "(0)." part?? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In scala any method taking a single parameter can be written with infix syntax.

So for instance if you have

```
class Foo(x: Int) {
   def add(y: Int) = x + y
}
val a = new Foo(42)
```

then these two method calls are exactly equivalent

```
a.add(4) // 46
a add 4  // 46
```

The reason why there's a parenthesis around the `0` is that in older versions of scala the `0.` would have been interpreted as a floating point number, due to the ambiguous value of `.` (which can be both a decimal separator and a method selector). Since scala 2.11 (or 2.10, I don't remember), this has been fixed, so you can now safely type

```
0.+(2) // Int: 2
```

and get an `Int` back, whereas you would have had a `Float` in the past, as the compiler would have seen it as

```
0.0 + (2) // Float: 2
```

Comment: In addition, integers and other primitive types are automatically converted to their equivalent object types. The value `0` is an integer and is automatically converted to `Int`. `Int` has a method `to()` which takes one integer argument.

Comment: @Bob, it's more the other way around. `Int` is an object type, which is then represented with a primitive in the underlying JVM.

Comment: deprecation in 2.10, new behavior in 2.11. The diff is in `val i = 0.;` which used to be a double but now an error.

Comment: @BobDalgleish There's a special implicit `Predef.intWrapper` to turn Int into a `runtime.RichInt`, which is different from boxing to Integer.

Answer (score 0):

> I mean, I can see that `to` is a function that takes one integer value as its parameter.

No, it's not a function, it's a method.

Methods are invoked by sending a message to an object:

```
foo.bar(baz)
```

This means "send the message `bar` with the object referenced by `baz` as argument to the object referenced by `foo`. This will in turn cause the method `bar` in `foo`'s class or one of its ancestors to be invoked.

So, `to` is the message, `2` is the argument, and `0` is the receiver of the message.

Scala allows you to use either a `.` or whitespace for message sending:

```
foo bar(baz)
// is the same as
foo.bar(baz)
```

Also, when using whitespace for message sending, you can leave off the parentheses of the last argument list if it has only a single argument:

```
foo bar baz
// is the same as
foo bar(baz)
```

And lastly, parentheses are not only used for argument lists, they are also used for grouping. (And tuple literals as well.) You can always surround an expression with parentheses to clarify its precedence:

```
(foo).bar(baz)
// is the same as
foo.bar(baz)
```